# Override variable from other recipe that is not soft assigned (?=)

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to change a variable value from another Yocto recipe that is not soft assigned '?='

For example

meta-layerA has a given recipe that sets variable `FOO="valueA"`

And I want to change `FOO` either in meta-layerB (custom recipe) or in local.conf

If meta-layerA has `FOO?="valueA"` I'm able to change `FOO` from local.conf.

Is there a way to change `FOO` even if '=' is used as assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a distro configuration you could use overrides, something like:

FOO_<distro_override> = "valueB"

to reset the variable when your distro is configured. In a .bbappend, a second assignment parsed after the first would override the original value so:

FOO = "value2"

would work too as it would reset the original value due to be parsed later.

Answer (score 2):

Create a bbappend in `meta-layerB` for the recipe which is in `meta-layerA` and just put `FOO = "valueb"` in it.